# jQuery: enable 2nd button after clicking on the first one

Tags: jquery

Is there a way to enable the second button after clicking on the first one?

```
<form method="post">
<fieldset>
    <legend>Option 1</legend>
    <input class="clickbox" type="radio" name="1" />1
    <br />
    <input class="clickbox" type="radio" name="1" />2
    <br />
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
    <legend>Option 2</legend>
    <input class="clickbox" type="radio" name="2" />1
    <br />
    <input class="clickbox" type="radio" name="2" />2
    <br />
</fieldset>
<input type="submit" value="Checkout" id="submitbutton" disabled="disabled" />
</form>

<br />
<input type="button" value="Next Button"  disabled="disabled">
```

[**DEMO ON JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/m4Yr2/16/)

Comment: What exactly is the second button? And what is the first one?
Do you want to show the next button when you click the checkout button?

Comment: You are submitting form, so there is no reason to unlock `Next button` user will not use it because he is redirected.

Comment: Side note: Radio buttons are missing `value` attribute. ([details](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_radio_value.asp))

Comment: @user3008011 - yes, I want to show the next button when checkout button has been clicked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<input type="submit" value="Checkout" id="submitbutton" disabled="disabled" class="submit button" />
<input type="button" id="nextButton" value="Next Button"  disabled="disabled">

<script>
$(function() {
$("#submitbutton").click(function() {
        $('#nextButton').attr('disabled', false);
   });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

worked here:

```
$('form input[type="radio"]').click(function () {
    var total = $('form fieldset').length;
    $('#submitbutton').prop('disabled', ($('input:checked').length === total) ? false : true)
});

$('#submitbutton').click(function(){
    if($(this).prop('disabled') == false)
    {
        $('input[type=button]:last').prop('disabled', '');
        alert("its work!");
    }
});
```